# VBA code for applying different percentage for last column of table

Tags: vba, excel

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range, n As Integer, i As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    Set r = Application.InputBox("Select the range", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If r Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    n = Application.InputBox("How many departments?")
    c = ActiveCell.Column
    r.Copy
    For i = 1 To n
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, c + (i - 1) * (r.Columns.Count + 1)).Activate
        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Next i
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

So far this macro,

1. Prompts the user to select a range. The range will be a table from another worksheet.
2. It then prompts the user again asking how many departments there are and depending on that number, it will copy the selected range a specific number of times in a new worksheet.
3. The next step is--depending on the department type--the user needs to input a percentage and apply that percentage to the last column of the selected range, which is sales revenue.

For example, if the user inputs there are 5 departments, it will copy the table 5 times across in a new worksheet. It then should prompt the user again asking what the percentage shares are for each of the 5 departments and multiply the last column (sales revenue) by their respective percentages. To better illustrate my point, here is a sample workbook:

[Dummy Data on GoogleDrive](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BYPtzo1_KkJlWB7Av51k2r-pppozNqzLAsg57cvb_Fk/edit#gid=0)

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: c isn't declared. Is that an oversight or a global variable?

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach -- when you copy over the values, replace the final column by a formula linked to the original range with a value underneath the copied column for the percentage. Allow the user to modify those percentages directly in the spreadsheet. Something like:

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range, n As Integer, i As Integer, c As Integer
    Dim vals As Variant
    Dim cRange As Range
    Dim pCell As Range 'to hold percentage
    Dim numRows As Integer, numCols As Integer
    Dim fcol As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Set r = Application.InputBox("Select the range", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If r Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    numCols = r.Columns.Count
    numRows = r.Rows.Count
    vals = r.Value

    fcol = r.Columns(numCols).Address
    fcol = "'" & r.Parent.Name & "'!" & fcol

    n = Application.InputBox("How many departments?")
    c = ActiveCell.Column
    Set cRange = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(numRows - 1, numCols - 1))
    For i = 1 To n
        cRange.Value = vals
        Set pCell = cRange.Cells(1, 1).Offset(numRows, numCols - 1)
        pCell.Value = 100 '=100%
        cRange.Columns(numCols).FormulaArray = "=" & fcol & " * " & "0.01 * " & pCell.Address
        pCell.Offset(1).Value = "Department " & i & "'s %"
        Set cRange = cRange.Offset(0, numCols + 1)
    Next i

End Sub
```

In this code I illustrated a standard way to transfer data using range objects value property and variant arrays. There is seldom need to select, copy and paste in VBA

Comment: Thanks, John. Is it possible to have the macro retrieve the percentage from B2, K2, S2, etc.? It depends how many departments there are, but there's a spot where I have to put the percentages anyway so might as well retrieve it from there. Take a look at the sample worksheet "Dept_Spread" to get a better idea of what I mean. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BYPtzo1_KkJlWB7Av51k2r-pppozNqzLAsg57cvb_Fk/edit#gid=0

Comment: One problem is that the actual cells which hold the percentages depend on the location of the active cell when the macro is invoked (as per your code). One possibility is to, in the loop that sets pCell, created a name for the cell in the Workbook's Name collection (but then you might want to be sure to clear the names when the sub is rerun). Then, for example, "Dept1Percent" could always refer to the cell that holds the percentage for department 1, no matter what cell was active when the sub was invoked.